# Token based authentication to call Netsuite API

Tags: magento2, netsuite

Get `Api` of Netsuite is not working with oauth 1.0 from php generated authentication header, but `Api` works from  Postman if we enable Oauth 1.0 in postman.

Postman generated Authorization Header :

```
OAuth realm="4819062_SB1",oauth_consumer_key="....oauth consumer kay.....",oauth_token=".....oauth token .....",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1532670855",oauth_nonce="KxFSDi",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="UutS6YGFswBuc94%2FigPADywIdp8%3D"
```

Authorization Header using `PHP` :

Authorization :

```
OAuth oauth_signature="YAVtWB2W05JIPJeOALedNDUQQzE%3D", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="9acdd26cc3edde48628b9d60c901de46", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key=".....oauth consumer key...", oauth_token="........auth token.......", oauth_timestamp="1532671431", realm="4819062_SB1"
```

`php` generated authorization header is not working :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT",
        "message": "Invalid login attempt."
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the PHP header values and sticking them into Postman and seeing they work? Try to capture the headers before the request is sent from your PHP app (and make sure it doesn't send) and then stick them into Postman and see if they work from Postman.

Comment: Hey Jon, Yes i have captured the headers and Stick in to Postman but it doesn't work , but both PHP header and Postman generated header looks similar.

Comment: Sounds like PHP is not generating the signature correctly. This might sound tedious but can you narrow it down to one parameter that is causing it to fail? Like one by one take the PHP parameters and switch the working Postman parameters with the PHP ones, you should be able to narrow it down to one or two that are causing it to fail. This will help debug.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple reasons as to why we will encounter an Invalid Login Attempt Error.

To know more details about the error, you can use the Login Audit Trail to track TBA tokens and users.

1. Go to **Setup** > **Users/Roles** > **User Management** > **View Login Audit Trail**.
2. Check the **Use Advanced Search** box
3. Click the **Results** subtab.
4. Add the following fields: **Detail**, **Token-based Access Token Name**, and **Token-based Application Name**.
5. Click **Submit**.

The **Detail** column displays error messages for any token-based authentication logins with a status of Failure. Please provide the error message on the details column so we can help you further.

Comment: As per your suggestion i have added columns In Search Criteria ,but in the Detail, Token-based Access Token Name and Token-based Application name Columns there is no  value present for Administrator role. i have activated token based authentication for the administrator and Integration record also.